# Blender render from video editor is pixelated

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, video-sequence-editor, video

I rendered a 880 frames animation with a framerate of 24fps at 1920x1080 px as PNGs with eevee. They are compressed with 15% (default setting).

Now I took my pictures and set them with some audio files in the video editor and rendered the video there as mp4 file. Sadly I get pixelated fragments. What can I do that it works better or is my whole way of rendering PNGs and then with sound a mp4 stupid.

[image: rendered PNG unsed in the clip]
[image: and thats out of the mp4 file]

Comment: Example screenshot?

Comment: It seems like high compression or low bit rate  of your codec setup. Try to change it into some lossless format ... if that help, than try adjust your compression format. BTW ... Default FFmpeg (Matroska, QuickTime, MP4 container with H.264 codec, works for me fine without issue (tested just your single frame).

Comment: You can just add sound only to the video editor, and it will render from the scene camera but add the sound.